# Error displaying Map after Upgrading to Skobbler 2.2.0

Tags: android, skmaps

I am developing an android app with Skobbler. After updating to the latest version of the Skobbler SDK (2.2.0) we got this problem

Sometimes the map just works. The Background is displayed and all the markers. But next time starting the App (without even change something) the background stays gray and it says:

```
E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /null/res/xhdpi/icon_map_popup_navigate.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /null/res/xhdpi/icon_map_popup_arrow.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

It seems like die SDK sometimes drops the path to the MapResources (null). The files are in place and as I said, sometimes it works.

The initialisation of the MapResources worked with the last Version. There were no Problems.

What I've changed:

- Added mapView.resume() and mapView.pause() in my MapActivity
- Replaced mercadorToGps and gpsToMercador with coordinateToPoint and pointToCoordinate because old Methods were removed
- Replaced zoomToLevel() with animateToZoomLevel() because old Methods were removed

I would love to use the new Version of the SDK, but as it is now I can't.

Comment: Check if the files/icons in the xhdpi folder are visible from the project (refresh) and then clean & rebuild the project? Any changes?

Comment: I've checked it again, but I do not excpect the problem at the files. Sometimes it does work so it can't be a missing / hidden file. But the LogCat shows that there is a missing / wrong path to the assets ressources folder. But this call is started in the SDK so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Create a demo project and send it to dev@skobbler.com as it seems an integration issue (no such issues can be reproduced with the demo project)

Comment: I have same problem.

Comment: I've got it. It seems there have been changes in the SDK regarding the initialisation. I had to move some code from onCreate() and onStart() to onResume() and onSurfaceCreated(). In addition, fitBoundingBox() and centerMapOnPosition() seems to have changed. In the past, setting an invalid GPS-Position did not work but did not create a bug, either. Now this let's the map not display background. Setting a BoundingBox with all 4 coords equal does the same.

Comment: So, right now the map correctly displays?

Comment: Hi, is solution found? i still face same issue.