# Skobbler Maps on Android showing black screen

Tags: android, skmaps

I'm using Skobbler SDK 2.3.0, targeting Lollipop, testing on a Nexus 5 and Galaxy S4, building on Android Studio 1.0.2.

I've a single MainActivity with a navigation drawer and fragments. I initialize Skobbler in the MainActivity and load the fragment that displays the maps. However, I only get a black screen with the watermark "Powered by Scout OSM" at the bottom right. Single and double taps are registered, but if I pinch to zoom the app crashes.

I don't see any errors in logcat before the app crashes. Can anyone help?

**Project structure:**

- app/libs/SKMaps.jar
- app/src/main/assets/SKMaps.zip
- app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libngnative.so
- app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libngnative.so
- app/src/main/jniLibs/x86/libngnative.so

**build.grade:**

```
dependencies {
...
...
compile files('libs/SKMaps.jar')
}
```

**logcat**

`01-05 22:58:42.835  26785-26785/com.example.android I/MainActivity﹕ onCreate
01-05 22:58:42.869  26785-26785/com.example.android I/System.out﹕ Item selected in navigation drawer
01-05 22:58:42.895  26785-26785/com.example.android I/MainActivity﹕ Adding login fragment
01-05 22:58:42.895  26785-26785/com.example.android I/MainActivity﹕ Done
01-05 22:58:42.895  26785-26785/com.example.android I/MainActivity﹕ Initialising Skobbler
01-05 22:58:42.899  26785-26785/com.example.android I/MainActivity﹕ Start initializeLibrary()
01-05 22:58:42.899  26785-26785/com.example.android D/SKMaps﹕ SKMapInitSettings---- Map style  [/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android/files/SKMaps/daystyle/ , daystyle.json ,-1]
01-05 22:58:42.899  26785-26785/com.example.android D/SKMaps﹕ SKVersionManager----setMapUpdateListener - com.example.android.MainActivity@1c8a98bc
01-05 22:58:42.899  26785-26785/com.example.android I/MainActivity﹕ End initializeLibrary()
01-05 22:58:42.899  26785-26785/com.example.android I/MainActivity﹕ Skobbler initialised
01-05 22:58:42.899  26785-26785/com.example.android I/MainActivity﹕ onCreate end
...
01-05 22:58:55.790  26785-26785/com.example.android D/SKMaps﹕ SKMapSurfaceView----SKMapSurfaceView constructor
01-05 22:58:55.790  26785-26785/com.example.android D/SKMaps﹕ SKMapSurfaceView----os model Nexus 5
01-05 22:58:55.797  26785-26785/com.example.android D/SKMaps﹕ MapRenderer----Set map density 3.0
01-05 22:58:55.800  26785-26785/com.example.android D/SKMaps﹕ SKMapSurfaceView---- ON PAUSE
01-05 22:58:55.803  26785-26785/com.example.android D/SKMaps﹕ SKMapSurfaceView----Saved  map cache state  [ Map Region zoom=17.0 center= [13.385000228881836,52.51665115356445]]  [Display mode=MODE_2D]   [Follower mode=NONE]   [Compass shown=false Position = [0.0 ,0.0] ]  [Rotation=true ] [Panning=true][Zooming=true]   [Bearing=0.0] [Annotations=0]
01-05 22:58:55.811  26785-26785/com.example.android E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: null/res/xhdpi/icon_map_popup_navigate.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-05 22:58:55.813  26785-26785/com.example.android E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: null/res/xhdpi/icon_map_popup_arrow.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-05 22:58:55.822  26785-26785/com.example.android D/SKMaps﹕ SKMapSurfaceView---- centerMapOnPosition [19.8171,41.3294]`

Comment: just wait the logcat will be displayed

Comment: Hi Adellah, what do you mean?

Comment: Hi, I just mean that you must see something in the logcat, because this is a bug in AS when the logcat doesn't displaye nothing ..

Comment: @Abdellah What I meant was, there are no errors shown in logcat to indicate what the problem is. My unrelated log output appears as normal.

Comment: I don't agree App Crash => Error

Comment: Have you tried the latest version(2.3)? It shows the same behavior?

Comment: @SylviA my bad, I'm using 2.3. More specifically, I got my files from SKMaps_Android_2.3.0_withDemo.zip

Comment: Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906499/error-displaying-map-after-upgrading-to-skobbler-2-2-0 Check the initialization process- it could be a similar problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing one statement after the map is initialized:

```
mapView.onResume();
```

If you have a look at the example from Skobbler you see they copy the textures in one `Activity` and show the map in a different one. The `Activity` that shows the map calls `mapView.onResume()` and `mapView.onPause()` in the `Activity` callbacks. If you want to load the textures and show the map in the same `Activity`, you'll have to call `mapView.onResume()` after the resources are copied and the map is initialized.

Comment: Thank you @Joris! I can finally see the map.

Comment: It looks like I have a similar error. Where did you put mapView.onResume();

Comment: @Distwo In the corresponding Activity callbacks when you're copying the resources in another activity then the one that is showing the map. Otherwise call it after you've copied the resources.

Comment: @Joris I tried that with no luck... Prob a different problem for me. Thank you though!

Comment: @Distwo pitty : -( You can have a look through the Skobbler example, maybe you can get that one to work and figure out your problem that way?