# SKMaps shows black / bluish background

Tags: android, skmaps

I am implementing turn-by-turn navigation in android using SKMaps. For this, I displayed a separate activity which uses SKMaps. When I present the activity for very first time, the map is displayed and the navigation is working. If I go back from this activity and start this navigation activity again, then it will display a screen with black/bluish background.But, the advice text panel, ETA panel, source and destination markers are displayed in the screen.

I referred this link [Skobbler Maps on Android showing black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781692/skobbler-maps-on-android-showing-black-screen) and checked my onCreate and onResume methods.

I have initialized the SKMap using "initializeSKMaps" method in "onCreate" and did "mapView.onResume" in "onResume" method.

Still I see the black/bluish background. Please provide some suggestions on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We discovered this bug on the 2.4 release - when in 3D navigation, the map (background) sometimes (on certain devices) becomes black (e.g. when returning from background). The map would restore if you were to switch the device in landscape mode.

This affected only the 2.4 release and it's connected to an OpenGL ES 2.0 issue (we moved to ES 2.0 with the 2.4 SDK version).

We've fixed the issue for 2.5. The 2.5 SDK version will be rolled out next week (in the week with 25-29 of May)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have changed the navigation mode from 3D to 2D. Now, it is working fine.