# I am Using offline SKMaps with prebundelled maps in android. Is there any way to save SKMAps.zip file into phone external storage?

Tags: android, skmaps

The application crashes with fatal signal 11 error. I think it is because of application size increases from 50mb. How i can place SKMaps.zip file in phone's external storage instead of placing it in assets folders.

Comment: Be specific and precise while asking questions See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have been able to save SKMaps.zip in phone's external storage but it is not loading offline maps and still taking me to berlin, Germany. I have added Offline maps for callifornia, USA

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation chapter](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec022) about hosting the maps on another storage.

Still I don't think the error is connected with the 50MBs limit.

Comment: I added maps successfully and its working now But another problem i am facing now is that when i come back to maps activity from other activity map shows black blocks instead of streets.
I searched for it and found this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366989/skmaps-shows-black-bluish-background
It say its the problem in sdk. If so how i can show navigation mode in 2d.

Comment: Most likely you are using multiple maps in your app - see the documentation chapter about this: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec033

Comment: If you need to change to 2D after starting navigation, call mapView.getMapSettings().setMapDisplayMode(SKMapSettings.SKMapDisplayMode.MODE_2D);